# Other Rows being re-rendered Flutter (UI dismissible issue)

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

```
// here paramskeyvaluePair is a map of int , object … int is the row number and object is  {key: " data" , value : " value " } 

Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6.8,
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                for (int key in paramskeyvaluePair.keys)
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(key.toString()),
                      Container(
                        child: buildRow(key),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                    ],
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

//add button
 InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      addParamsRow();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add_circle_rounded,
                    size: 20,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),

 
// functions 
void addParamsRow() {
    if (paramskeyvaluePair.isEmpty) {
      paramskeyvaluePair[0] = {"key": "", "value": ""};
    } else {
      int maxKey = paramskeyvaluePair.keys.reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);
      int newKey = maxKey + 1;
      paramskeyvaluePair[newKey] = {"key": "", "value": ""};
    }
  }

  void deleteParamsRow(int rowKey) {
    setState(() {
      paramskeyvaluePair.remove(rowKey);
    });
  }


  Widget buildRow(int index) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 30,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                width: 2.6,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  print(value);
                  // if (_linkcontroller.text.isEmpty) {
                  //   showSnackbar(
                  //       "Link cannot be empty",
                  //       "Enter a link where you want to add parameters !!!",
                  //       "failure");
                  //   setState(() {});
                  //   return;
                  // }
                  setState(() {
                    paramskeyvaluePair[index]['key'] = value;
                  });
                  // setState(() {});
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Key',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 30,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                width: 2.6,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    paramskeyvaluePair[index]['value'] = value;
                  });
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Value',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              deleteParamsRow(index);

              print('=======>> $paramskeyvaluePair ');
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.delete,
              size: 20,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

There's a problem with deleting a row in the paramskeyvaluePair. Although the deletion works fine, the issue is that when you remove a row above, it causes all the rows below it to refresh in the user interface, which is not what we want. Only remove the particular row not refresh other Rows below that Row.

Comment: You call setState and modify paramskeyvaluePair, which seems to rebuild your ListView.
What do you mean when you say "not refresh other rows below"?